# How to get jspwiki-custom.properties to work on JSPWiki on Tomcat?

Tags: linux, tomcat, wiki

I've got Tomcat 8.5.23 running on Linux (Slackware 14.1) just fine, and am trying to get JSPWiki 2.10.3 to work.  The "easy-sh" installation, which consists of dropping JSPWiki.war into the webapps directory of Tomcat works.  However, after running the near-useless JSPWiki/Install.jsp, I cannot get it to find and use my jspwiki-custom.properties file.  The [Getting Started](https://jspwiki-wiki.apache.org/Wiki.jsp?page=Getting%20Started) page, says that "The custom file can also be placed in the WEB-INF folder of the WAR...", but that doesn't work.  The [Documentation](https://jspwiki-wiki.apache.org/Wiki.jsp?page=Documentation) page says it can be placed in "webapps//WEB-INF/classes folder", but that also didn't work.  The log file has some specific lines that state jspwiki cannot find it.

So am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that anyone would seem to care, but somehow it started working with the jspwiki-custom.properties in the "webapps/WEB-INF/classes" directory.

I'm not sure, but I think there was a mismatch in the webapp name that may have resolved the issue.